# Raspberry and nodered-nodejs-npm SyntaxError

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I'm trying to install a sensor node in nodered for my raspberry pi3. The sensor is the air quality sensor SDS011, and the command to install it is the following:

```
npm install node-red-contrib-sds011
```

allright then, I think that is a problem with some updates, actually the command

```
node -v
```

gives me "v4.4.5" as answer.

The problem is that when i try to use some npm commands, as the one above for the sensor, i'll get always this error as answer:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Furthermore, if i try to launch the node.red console, a similar error appears:

```
Starting as a systemd service.                                                                            
/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:93                                   
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {                                                          
                                      ^^^                                                                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...                                                                         
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                             
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                           
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)                                                                  
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/                          lib/index.js:6:3)                                                                                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                       
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                          
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.                                    
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.                                          
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:93                                   
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {                                                          
                                      ^^^                                                                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...                                                                         
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                             
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                           
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)                                                                  
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/                          lib/index.js:6:3)                                                                                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                       
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                          
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.                                    
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.                                          
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:93                                   
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {                                                          
                                      ^^^                                                                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...                                                                         
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                             
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                           
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)                                                                  
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/                          lib/index.js:6:3)                                                                                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                       
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                          
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.                                    
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.                                          
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.                                                             
/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:93                                   
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {                                                          
                                      ^^^                                                                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...                                                                         
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                             
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                           
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)                                                                  
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/                          lib/index.js:6:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:93
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {
                                      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:6:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
nodered.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
```

some suggestions?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS v4.4.5 is VERY old and totally out of support (it went EOL in April 2018).

Node-RED currently requires at least NodeJS version 8.x (https://nodered.org/docs/faq/node-versions)

You will need to upgrade your system, I suggest you use the script linked to from [here](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi) as it will upgrade to the latest NodeJS and Node-RED.